# Autoloading a class in Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony-2.1

I'm porting a Symfony 1.2 project to Symfony 2.x. I'm currently running the latest 2.1.0-dev release.

From my old project I have a class called Tools which has some simple functions for things like munging arrays into strings and generating slugs from strings. I'd like to use this class in my new project but I'm unclear how to use this class outside of a bundle.

I've looked at various answers here which recommend changing app/autoload.php but my autoload.php looks different to the ones in the answers, maybe something has changed here between 2.0 and 2.1.

I'd like to keep my class in my src or app directories as they're under source control. My vendors directory isn't as I'm using composer to take care of that.

Any advice would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a simple case like this the quickest solution is creating a folder (for example `Common`) directly under `src` and put your class in it.

```
src
  -- Common
    -- Tools.php
```

`Tools.php` contains your class with proper namespace, for example

```
<?php

namespace Common;

class Tools
{
    public static function slugify($string)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Before calling your function do not forget the `use` statement

```
use Common\Tools;

// ...
Tools::slugify('my test string');
```

If you put your code under `src` following the proper folder structure and namespace as above, it will work without touching `app/autoload.php`.

Comment: Awesome, I put my class in Lib\Tools and Symfony autoloaded it fine. Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I asked reason here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652384/symfony2-custom-class-not-found. Please help if you know why it doesn't work

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to use the /app/config/autoload.php:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add( 'YOURNAMESPACE', __DIR__.'/../vendor/YOURVENDOR/src' );


// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once  _DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Just replace YOURNAMESPACE and YOURVENDOR with your values. Works quite well for me, so far.

You're correct, I stumbled upon the changes in autoload from 2.0 to 2.1. The above code works fine with the latest version, to which I upgraded my project ;-)

Comment: +1 Great! Finally found what I was looking for. This should go in the Symfony doc.

Comment: Is this still the proper way to load custom PSR-0 compliant vendor libraries that aren't part of Packagist?

Comment: No, it is not... Since the autoload now is done via generated autoloader by composer, all your namespaced classes in vendor should be available.