# Symfony autoloading structure

Tags: php, symfony

Good evening!

I have a little problem accessing custom classes in symfony2.1.6 using the 
autoloader.
What I need to do is access the 
 Mangress/src/Qkprod/Classes/api/APIEntry.php class from within the 
 DefaultController. Apparently I am too stupid to find a way to extend 
 the autoload.php to do that. Now I am at a point where I have been 
 reading so many blogposts and solutions that I don't know anymore 
 what to do anymore...

My file structure looks as follows:

```
Mangress
 -app
 -src
    -Qkprod
      -MangressBundle
      -Controller, Entity, Resources, Tests
      -Classes
         -api
            -APIEntry.php
         -db
         -security
    -QkprodMangressBundle.php
 -vendor
 -web
```

The Classes folder contains all the classes I have written so far.

What I have read so far was that I need to register the Namespaces of 
 the classes to load in the **Mangress/app/autoload.php**
 [Autoloading a class in Symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045554/autoloading-a-class-in-symfony-2-1)

> $loader->add('Qkprod\MangressBundle\api',
>                  **DIR**.'/../src/Qkprod/MangressBundle/Classes/api/');
>   Though this seems to be wrong..

Is there something wrong with my naming or understanding of symfony?
I register the Namespace **"Qkprod\MangressBundle\api"** to the autoloader 
so that symfony knows where to look when

> use Qkprod\MangressBundle\api\APIEntry;

So it has to look in my **Mangress/src/Qkprod/MangressBundle/Classes/api** 
folder am I wrong?

I would really appreciate some guidance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using the [directory structure](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html) recommended by symfony developers?

And not even just symfony developers, this structure is called [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), and is adopted by many PHP frameworks.

If you stay with the conventions, the default autoloader will load your classes just fine, and other developers will understand your code more easier.

Just remove your "Classes" directory, and move everything from it a level upwards:

```
Mangress
 -app
 -src
    -Qkprod
      -MangressBundle
        -Controller, Entity, Resources, Tests
        -Api
          -APIEntry.php
        -Db
         -security
        -QkprodMangressBundle.php
 -vendor
 -web
```

This way when you write

```
use Qkprod\MangressBundle\Api\APIEntry
```

It will know where to look.

Comment: THANK YOU! Thats why I wanted to ask.. cause I was kinda confused as to what I should do and what not. Also completely missed these conventions. Its finally really working now. I will look into your references in detail. Thanks a lot! Now I can finally start programming ;)