# Symfony2 - Class Not Found

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I have added custom class under `/src/Common` directory as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052003/1071156) I do everything as described in link but it doesn't work. I can't understand why. Thank you in advance for help.

**Custom Class:** HttpClient.class.php

```
namespace Common;

class HttpClient {...
```

**Controller:**

```
use Common\HttpClient;

$httpClient = new HttpClient();
```

**Error:**

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Common\HttpClient' not found in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is my class exstension. It was `.class.php` and I changed it to `.php` and everything works now.