# Symfony custom class autoloading doesn`t work

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony 2.4.0. I want to use my custom class as discussed here: [Autoloading a class in Symfony 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045554/autoloading-a-class-in-symfony-2-1/12052003#12052003). I have created subfolder in `src`:

```
namespace Yur;

class MyClass {
    public go() {
        var_dump('hello!! 32');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I made this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Yur\MyClass;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $my = new MyClass();
        $my->go();
        die();
 ...
```

but it makes an exception:

*ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MyClass" from namespace "Yur" in /var/www/shop.loc/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/WelcomeController.php line 12. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?*

After I have got this exception, I decided consciously to make `syntax error` exception in my class to see if it loaded. I changed `class MyClass ...` to `class4 MyClass ...`, but doesn`t got a`syntax error` exception. And I decided, that my class is not loaded. 
Is anyone knows why? And what I must to do to resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things.  First, in your code sample above, you have

```
public go() {
    var_dump('hello!! 32');
}
```

which should be

```
public function go() {
    var_dump('hello!! 32');
}
```

The former raises a parser error in PHP. and probably isn't what you want.

Second, the error

> ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "MyClass" from namespace "Yur" in /var/www/shop.loc/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/WelcomeController.php line 12. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

is the error Symfony uses when it attempt to autoload a class, but can't find the file.  This usually means your file is named incorrectly, or in the wrong folder.  I'd tripped check that you have a file in the directory you think you do.

```
$ ls src/Yur/MyClass.php
```

You can also add some debugging to the composer autoload code to see what path it's cooking up for your custom class

```
#File: vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php
public function findFile($class)
{
    //...
    $classPath .= strtr($className, '_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '.php';

    //start your debugging code
    if($class == 'Yur\MyClass')
    {
        //dump the generated path
        var_dump($classPath);

        //dump the default include paths
        var_dump($this->fallbackDirs);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem was in that I don`t know that klassname and filename must be the same. I made it various. This helps me to determine where problem is:
`$ ls src/Yur/MyClass.php`

Comment: I spent a couple hours not noticing a minor misspelling in a file name, generating this error. Your findFile() tip helped. (I didn't use the sample code, but once I stepped that far into the debugger, I found the issue stepping into this function call within findFile(): $file = $this->findFileWithExtension($class, '.php');